# Is it possible to put this string into an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string of text, for example

```
"{"Date": 01/01/2019, "0": "John", "1": "Jack", "3": "Tom", "4": "Will", "5": "Joe"}"
```

Also, I have an entity

```
public class demo {
    public string firstValue { get; set; }
    public string secondValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to transform the string of text into the entity? For example,

`"Date"` goes to `firstValue`

`01/01/2019` goes to `secondValue`

---

`"0"` goes to `firstValue`

`"John"` goes to `secondValue`

Comment: Yes, you can get it. Use `var someObject = Json.Decode(<yourstring>);` . And then read the property and it's value one by one.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do that?

Comment: JSON convert it to an object that matches the schema, then shred it by hand. If you (for some reason) don't want to create an intermediate class, use a dynamic. To echo @mjwills, why do want to do this? It doesn't feel like something I'd ever want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided it's valid Json and the 01/01/2019 string is in quotes, this works:

```
class demo
{
    public string firstValue { get; set; }
    public string secondValue { get; set; }
}

string json = "{\"Date\": \"01/01/2019\", \"0\": \"John\", \"1\": \"Jack\", \"3\": \"Tom\", \"4\": \"Will\", \"5\": \"Joe\"}";
var obj = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
List<demo> children = obj.Children().Select(c => new demo()
{
    firstValue = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)c).Name,
    secondValue = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)c).Value.ToString()
}).ToList();  

foreach (var ch in children)
{
    Console.WriteLine("firstValue: {0}, secondValue: {1}", ch.firstValue, ch.secondValue);
}
```

Writes:

```
firstValue: Date, secondValue: 01/01/2019
firstValue: 0, secondValue: John
firstValue: 1, secondValue: Jack
firstValue: 3, secondValue: Tom
firstValue: 4, secondValue: Will
firstValue: 5, secondValue: Joe
```